# android voice recorder start failed ? but 0 size file get created

Tags: android

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC );
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);



recorder.setMaxDuration(10000 * 10); 
recorder.setOnInfoListener(null); 
recorder.setOutputFile(s+"/sh1.3gp");
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


    try {  
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND);
        recorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        recorder.prepare(); 
        recorder.start();
        }  
    catch (Exception e2) {
            tv.setText("OHH"+e2.toString());

            }
```

above is code to play the recorder
.
when i start the recorder it gives start failed:

but file  sh1.3gp (a 3gp file ) file gets created in android sd card ..
.
Do please reply me the solution

Comment: Just try [this](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code on emulator? If so, you must try to run on a real device because you cannot save audio with emulator without changing its settings. Easier way is testing on a real(Hardware) device.

Comment: sir, i run this program apk in my samsung also  .. there also get start failed.

Comment: if so, look that example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to record audio.
Create object of recorder.  and
File audioFile=null;

```
File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
try {
audiofile = File.createTempFile("Recording", ".3gp", sampleDir);
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();  
    }
    catch (IOException e)
   {
   Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
   return;
}
```

And you can save this Audio in SD card using following code.

```
audioFileName=input.getText().toString();
current = System.currentTimeMillis();
String artist = "" + getResources().getText(R.string.artistName);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, audioFileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,  current );
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, artist);              
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
ConntentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Uri newUri1 = contentResolver.insert(base, values);
```

Comment: sir , iam directly  storing the  the audio  3gp to my sd card  there , .3gp file gets created . then suddenly  start failed error comes :